# Is this real Commodore C386SX-LT

Tags: commodore, identify-this-computer

Is the model shown on pictures an authentic Commodore C386SX-LT? Why does it look different to other photos on the Internet (some additional grey keys? above keyboard):

http://www.spacereh.de/hc/com/sx386lt.htm

[image: front]

[image: top]

[image]

Comment: Easier to answer if you can give the source of the pictures.

Comment: This is an ebay find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for resources on Commodore C386SX LT](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/looking-for-resources-on-commodore-c386sx-lt)

Comment: Please do not open multiple questions about the same item. If necessary, modify the original question.

Comment: By the early 90s, Commodore was no longer developing / designing their own PCs, just selling Commodore-badged units from contract manufacturers. So the most likely explanation is that they had more than one source, or switched source. Commodore was really unravelling at this point.

Comment: The Commodore C386SX-LT was apparently sold in two versions.
See this site: https://www.scuzzscink.com/amiga/amiga_scuzz373.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Summarising the comments above by UncleBod and myself as an answer.)

By the early 90s, Commodore was no longer developing / designing their own PCs, as they had done [from the PC-10 through to the PC-50](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_PC-10_bis_PC-70). Instead, they moved to selling Commodore-badged units from contract manufacturers.

As part of this process, the case design moved from the typical duotone beige of earlier Commodore offerings (which can also be seen in e.g. the C-64C, the C-128, and the Amiga 2000) to a generic whatever-was-cheapest, as can be seen quite nicely [here](http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/cpcs2.html) and [here](http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/cpcs3.html).

By the time the C386SX LT came around, it seems Commodore had stopped caring about a consistent "brand appearance" altogether: The C386SX LT was sourced from at least two manufacturers, with very different cases. A side-by-side comparison of both models can be seen [here](http://scuzzscink.com/amiga/amiga_scuzz373.htm).